# gen_server , a server can’t call its own API functions?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

When I read Erlang OTP Action book,  I found this reminder on page 117:

With your RPC server, you can try calling any function exported from any module available  on  the  server  side,  except  one:  your  own tr_server:get_count/0.  In general, **a server can’t call its own API functions.** Suppose you make a synchronous call to the same server from within one of the callback functions: for example, **if handle_info/2 tries to use the get_count/0 API function. It will then perform a gen_server:call(...) to itself. But that request will be queued up until after the current call to handle_info/2 has finished, resulting in a circular wait—the server is deadlocked.**

But I looked at the tr_server sample code :

```
get_count() ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, get_count).   

stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, stop).

handle_info({tcp, Socket, RawData}, State) ->                   
    do_rpc(Socket, RawData),
    RequestCount = State#state.request_count,
    {noreply, State#state{request_count = RequestCount + 1}};
......
do_rpc(Socket, RawData) ->
try
    {M, F, A} = split_out_mfa(RawData),
    Result = apply(M, F, A),  %  tr_server process -> handle_info -> do_rpc ->call & cast                                
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, io_lib:fwrite("~p~n", [Result]))       
catch
    _Class:Err ->
        gen_tcp:send(Socket, io_lib:fwrite("~p~n", [Err]))
end.
```

I found the examples and cautions in the book inconsistent , the gen_server:call and gen_server:cast by tr_server process ownself.
Am I misinterpreting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `gen_server:cast` from within the server process is fine, because it is asynchronous: it adds the message to the mailbox of the process and then continues, returning `ok`.  Only `gen_server:call` has this problem, because it makes the process wait for an answer from itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  If gen_server:cast is called in do_rpc, cast is asynchronous  `Result = apply(M, F, A),gen_tcp:send(Socket, io_lib:fwrite("~p~n", [Result])) ` , How does the return logic work here?  Here need to return data to the client ,Does it mean do_rpc just support gen_server:call invoke？

Comment: If `apply(M, F, A)` ends up calling `gen_server:cast`, then `Result` will be the atom `ok`, and it will return `ok` to the client over the TCP socket without waiting for the operation to finish. So `split_out_mfa` would have to be carefully written to never return any function that could call `gen_server:call` for this process.

Comment: Oh, I get the idea. The examples in the book are just demos and not suitable for production. If I want to make a multiplayer game, when the client process receives TCP data, it parses it and sends it via `gen_server:cast` to the different function module server processes. The module server processes the information via `handle_cast` and sends the results to the client. The standard practice is that the server process itself should not call its own `gen_server:call` or `gen_server:cast`, right?

Comment: Exactly. In almost all cases the server process would not send messages to itself, it would just process one incoming message after another.

Comment: The question itself is the answer. I was confused by the examples in the book. Thank you again for your answer.